# Find the last applied seed value on a table in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a table and inserted 4 rows into it. I ran the below query

```
SELECT seed_value as SeedValue, last_value as identityValue 
FROM sys.identity_columns 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('ALJtest1')
```

and got the result as

```
SeedValue| identityValue
-------------------------
1        |    4
```

Then I reseeded the table using

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('DBO.ALJtest1', RESEED, 10)
```

When I ran the below query this time

```
SELECT seed_value as SeedValue, last_value as identityValue 
FROM sys.identity_columns 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('ALJtest1')
```

I got the result as

```
SeedValue| identityValue
-------------------------
1        |    10
```

Is there a way to find the last applied seed value on a table in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RESEED`, despite the name, doesn't change the identity's seed value, instead it simply sets the next identity value to generate. There is no way to change an identity column's actual seed value after it's created. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

> The seed value is the value inserted into an identity column for the
>   very first row loaded into the table. All subsequent rows contain the
>   current identity value plus the increment value where current identity
>   value is the last identity value generated for the table or view.
>
> You cannot use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` to perform the following tasks:
>
> - Change the original seed value that was specified for an identity column when the table or view was created.
> - Reseed existing rows in a table or view.
>
> To change the original seed value and reseed any existing rows, you
>   must drop the identity column and recreate it specifying the new seed
>   value. When the table contains data, the identity numbers are added to
>   the existing rows with the specified seed and increment values. The
>   order in which the rows are updated is not guaranteed.

So to answer your question: no, there is no way to know the last value specified in a `DBCC CHECKIDENT(..., RESEED)`, because the current identity value may have already changed after inserts.